# Calling C# (.NET) APIs from C

Tags: c#, .net, c

To invoke a C API from C# I would use P/Invoke. But if I were to do the reverse, call .NET APIs from C, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it all through C APIs and do an end run around COM and C++ you could do the following.  But first figure out if it's truly necessary!  I suspect in most cases it won't be.

Step 1. Create the C# .Net assembly you wish to call.

Step 2. Create a mixed mode CLI/C++ assembly with extern "C" functions exported.  Have this assembly call the C$ assembly.

Step 3. Create your C application that calls the exported C style functions from the DLL made in step 2.

Things to consider.
A. Is there an actual NEED to have a C (versus C++/COM) app directly call a .Net assembly?
In other words, why not use C++ and COM to COM exported .Net methods if you really must have a mixed (.Net and non-.Net) application/system?

B. Will the APIs you write be wrappers on classes? If so, how will you manage their life times? (e.g. Will you create/use handles? How will you manage their relationships to the actual gc objects...etc)

C. Strings. These are handled very different between C and .Net.  Make sure you're familiar with their differences and how to properly send strings across these boundaries...Hint: CString is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution that can avoid using COM or C++\CLI. See here: [Calling A .NET Managed Method from Native Code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953836/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

you can turn c# code into COM, or use C++\CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It implements [DllExport] attribute
https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

So one can do something like this to call managed code from unmanaged code:

C# code

```
class Test
{
     [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
     public static int Add(int left, int right)
     {
         return left + right;
     } 
}
```

C code

```
 int main()
 {
      int z = add(5,10);
      printf("The solution is found!!! Z is %i",z);
      return 0;
 }
```